# Should I keep SFTP connection open between periodical synchronizations?

Tags: sftp, synchronize, winscp

I want to upload every 30 seconds via SFTP (using WinSCP commands in MATLAB). Script is running fine: connecting, synchronizing, closing.

```
winscp.com /command "open xx@xxx.com/dir" "synchronize remote -mirror dir" "exit"
```

Now: for this continuously script, is it smarter to reconnect (and close after finished) every time or is there no problem just staying connect and synchronize every 30 sec?

Answer (score 1):

WinSCP does not have any "pause" command nor any kind of loop control structure. So you cannot stay connected, using just the simple WinSCP scripting interface.

You would have to use some more advanced technique, such as [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) and code the loop/pause in PowerShell or other language.

To actually answer your question: I do not think it really matters. Solution with reconnecting is definitely easier to implement. If you wanted to stay connected, you would have to implement also reconnection (in case connection is lost).

Comment: alright, so its totally legal (no problem) connecting every 30 seconds to this webhost. or do you think i should go for .net (like you said) to 'unburden' the server and my pc ?

Comment: Keeping connection alive all the time also wastes resources. Depends on what resources are more scarce in your case (CPU or memory).